# Meaning of ご休憩一時間コース

Tags: meaning

Can anyone help me understand what Hiragi means by "ご休憩一時間コース" in the below? Is this to be understood literally, or does it have some other type of meaning?

> 二人の顔がゆっくりと近づき、 その唇同士が触れ合おうとした瞬間、横から声が聞こえた。
>
> 「じ～～～～～～……」
>
> 「ん…… 　ん？」
>
> 「どわああああ！　ヒイラギー！？ 　おまおま、お前、いつからそこにー！？」
>
> 「いつからと問われるならば答えましょう。 先程からずっとです」
>
> 「正直、気付いてくれるのを待っていたのですが……」
>
> 「お二人のイチャつきがＭＡＸになると本格的に出られなくなると言いますか、**ご休憩一時間コース**かなと思い……」
>
> 「きゅ、休憩一時間って…… 　そ、そんなわけあるかーーー！」

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a reference to a Japanese "love hotel" (*rabuho*) and the activity people typically do there. The keyword "休憩/rest" is a good indicator that tells us a hotel is a "love hotel". See: https://savvytokyo.com/japans-love-hotels-what-you-need-to-know-before-you-go/